# I am getting 'wired network unmanaged' problem while connecting to internet

Tags: networking, wired

As per the solutions available on ubuntu I tried to do following:
`vim etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and then I tried to modify `managed=false` to `managed=true` in the *conf* file, but since it is a read only file so I could not do so. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the elevated command feature to edit systemwide files. Try the `sudoedit` command, which will write the file for you as root.

Try:

```
$ sudoedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

*By the way, the dollar sign ("$") is an important part of this answer.  It's showing that you're typing the command at the normal user's prompt.  There would be a pound sign ("#") if you were typing the command at the superuser's prompt.*